# How to goto top onClick function using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have link button when I click a div with content will show and at that time I want to scroll page to top with few pixels so that to be appear Div will show.

Code :

```
$('.preference-visibility').click(function(event) {
    $('.other-filters').toggle("slow", function(){
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $('#search_txt').html('SHOW LESS PREFERENCE');
             $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".main-filters").offset().top
                }, 2000);
        }else{
            $('#search_txt').html('SHOW MORE PREFERENCE');
        }
    });
});
```

this is `.main-filters` upper div of Link(which I click)

How to do this ?

Comment: Please include the HTML too. It will be easier to understand what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
   scrollTop: 0
}, 2000, 'easeInOutExpo');
```

Comment: What is `easeInOutExpo` ?